# Preserving conservation properties across time-integration schemes

Tags: pde, nonlinear-equations, time-integration

I am interested in deriving an accurate, implicit discretization of a nonlinear advection-diffusion equation
$$
\partial_t f = \frac{1}{v^2} \partial_v J(f,v) \equiv F(f,v) \tag{$\star$} 
$$
with flux
$$
J(f,v) = C(f,v) f + D(f,v) \partial_v f
$$
where $f(v,t)$ is the unknown function of a radial coordinate $v\in [0,\infty)$, and $C$ and $D$ are linear integral operators on $f$. In the physics context where this comes up, the operator $F$ satisfies two conservation laws,
$$
\int_0^\infty v^2 F \,dv = 0  \qquad \int_0^\infty v^4 F\,dv=0
$$
and there is also a positivity requirement, $f(v,t) > 0$. Historically, there has been a good deal of effort spent on designing finite-difference schemes such that a first-order update of ($\star$) satisfies these constraints to a high degree of accuracy.

The issue is that in practice, $F$ is not the only operator driving $\partial_t f$, and for some of these other operators - call them $A(f,v,t)$ - I would like to use at least second-order time integration schemes. The naive approach would be to use operator splitting, keeping the conservative first-order discretization for $F$ while using a higher-order scheme for $A$. But the overall accuracy of the scheme can never be better than first order in time, limited by the backward Euler update for $F$. So I am looking for something fancier.

I have heard of "strong stability preserving" methods. My rough understanding is that given a semi-discrete scheme that obeys certain constraints under a forward Euler update, then SSP methods can preserve these constraints for other time-stepping schemes. Are conservation properties like the above included in the class of constraints that an SSP scheme can preserve? My thought is to find a second-order (or higher) SSP scheme that is suitable for $A$ without ruining the conservation properties of $F$. Does this make sense, or is my understanding wrong?

Edit:

In response to comments, I'll write out the discretization of the operator $F$ (note I have made a minor change to the definition of the flux above). The nonlinearity is handled by simple fixed-point iteration, and I use a superscript "$*$" to mark quantities that are treated as "constant" and then re-evaluated at each stage of the iteration.

The equation is implicitly differenced in time and the divergence of the flux $J$ is computed from a central difference of values at cell boundaries (fractional indices)
$$
\frac{f^{n+1}_k - f^n_k}{\Delta t} = \frac{J^{n+1}_{k+\frac12} - J^{n+1}_{k-\frac12}}{v_k^2 \Delta v}
$$
The flux at cell boundaries is constructed as
$$
J^{n+1}_{k+\frac12} = C^*_{k+\frac12} f^{n+1}_{k+\frac12} + D^*_{k+\frac12} \frac{f^{n+1}_{k+1} - f^{n+1}_k}{\Delta v}
$$
The value of $f$ at the cell boundary is interpolated using the values from adjacent cell centers:
$$
f^{n+1}_{k+\frac12} = (1 - \delta^*_{k+\frac12}) f^{n+1}_{k+1} + \delta^*_{k+\frac12} f^{n+1}_k
$$
where the interpolation weight is
$$
\delta^*_{k+\frac12} = \frac{1}{w^*_{k+\frac12}} - \frac{1}{\exp(w^*_{k+\frac12}) - 1} ,\qquad w^*_{k+\frac12} = \Delta v \frac{C^*_{k+\frac12}}{D^*_{k+\frac12}}
$$
The "coefficients" $C^*_{k+\frac12}$ and $D^*_{k+\frac12}$ are evaluated at each iteration using midpoint quadrature. The $C$ quadrature needs only $f^*_k$ (cell centers), but the $D$ quadrature uses $f^*_{k+\frac12}$ (cell edges). Since the interpolation weights $\delta^*_{k+\frac12}$ are themselves functions of $D^*_{k+\frac12}$, an inner iteration is performed to ensure the $\delta$'s and $D$'s are consistent.

The comment by @DavidKetcheson mentions that if the above scheme were linear, then it could in principle be used in an RK scheme and still have the desired conservation properties. However, after writing things out, I think the dependence of the interpolation weights $\delta_{k+\frac12}$ on the unknowns $f_k$ is nonlinear, so there is no guarantee that this scheme can be trivially made to work with a higher-order time-integrator without sacrificing conservation properties. Is that the end of the story?

Comment: Honestly, some of the things that you write actually do not make sense. I don't even know how to begin to answer your question. As a first step you may rethink the definition range of your PDE.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with $[0, \infty)$. Would you rather I write $[0, v_{\max}]$? If you can point out a few phrases that seem mixed up or missing context, that would help get me on track.

Comment: You don't need anything fancy. The properties you want to preserve are linear in $f$, so if you have a linear semidiscretization that preserves them, any Runge-Kutta method will preserve them.

Comment: @Endulum Dividing by zero is no good idea.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson Thanks for that tip. In my problem the operator $F$ is bilinear in the unknown via the products $C f$ and $D \partial_v f$. Does that preclude a "linear semidiscretization"? That's a new term for me. If you're willing to write something brief about that with a reference or two for further reading, I'd consider that a helpful answer.

Comment: Oh, I  hadn't noticed that.  If you can write down a semidiscretization of the full problem that conserves the quantities you want, it would be easier to see whether that will automatically be preserved.

Comment: I've edited in details about the scheme. I suspect that this a nonlinear discretization, but I am holding out hope that there is still something I can do with it.